# How to convert multiple selected column names from integer to date in r

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a data set with column names that look like this.

**INPUT**

```
Country  X1.22.20 X1.23.20 X1.24.20 X1.25.20 X1.26.20 X1.27.20 
    India      40        20      30       21       25      28
    USA        21        22      23       45       32      19
    CHINA      30        45      32       46       78      48
```

X1.22.20 represents 1/22/2020

**Required Output**

```
Country  01/22/20 01/23/20 01/24/20 01/25/20 01/26/20 01/27/20 
     India      40        20      30       21       25      28
     USA        21        22      23       45       32      19
     CHINA      30        45      32       46       78      48
```

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid this conversion, if we read with `check.names = FALSE`

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

---

if we already read it without the `check.names = FALSE` option, convert to `Date` class and then `format`

```
names(df1)[-1] <- format(as.Date(names(df1)[-1], format = "X%m.%d.%y"), "%m/%d/%y")
```

---

Or another option is `sub`

```
names(df1)[-1] <- sub("^X(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)", "\\1/\\2/\\3", names(df1)[-1])
```